# JobStore Quartz not saving history

Tags: c#, .net, database, jobs, quartz.net

I'm new with quartz, and I'm trying to get quartz to persist everytime it runs the job.

I have already created the QRTZ_ tables according to Quartz database, and I made quartz connect to my database, but after running a job, it saves nothing on QRTZ_ tables. Should I save it manually? Or am I missing some config? Here is my code:

**EDIT: Found an exception in here:**

```
scheduler.Start();
```

Getting a Null Reference Exception, dont know why

Config file:

```
<quartz>
<add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="MyScheduler"/>
<add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceId" value="instance_one"/>
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10"/>
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal"/>

<add key="quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime" value ="5000"/>
<add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000"/>
<add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz"/>
<add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_"/>
<add key="quartz.jobStore.clustered" value="false"/>
<add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz"/>

<add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="localhost"/>
<add key="quartz.dataSource.MySqlServerFullVersion.connectionStringName" value="C3MContext"/>
<add key="quartz.dataSource.MySqlServerFullVersion.connectionString" value="User ID=****;Password=****;Initial Catalog=novo_canalcc;Data Source=localhost"/>
<add key="quartz.dataSource.MySqlServerFullVersion.provider" value="SqlServer-20"/>
<add key="quartz.dataSource.useProperties" value="false"/>
```

Configuring the job:

```
var config = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("quartz");

            ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(config);

            //ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            IScheduler scheduler = sf.GetScheduler("MyScheduler");
            scheduler.Start();

            foreach (var job in Jobs)
            {
                Log.Info($"Start schedule Job: {job}");

                IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create(job.GetType()).StoreDurably().Build();

                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule
                      (s =>
                         s.WithIntervalInMinutes(job.IntervalInMinutes)
                        .RepeatForever()
                      )
                    .Build();

                scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);

                Log.Info($"Job schedule started: {job}");
            }
```

Here is my Job test class:

```
public class Class1 : IC3MJob
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Class1));

    public Class1()
    {
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Log.Trace($"=========== {GetType().Name} started on: ===>>: {DateTime.Now}");

        //Do something

        Log.Trace($"=========== {GetType().Name} executed/finished on: ===>>: {DateTime.Now}");
    }

    public int IntervalInMinutes => Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["job.poc"]);
}
```

And I'm calling the job like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void test()
    {
        JobSchedule.Jobs.Add(new Class1());
        JobSchedule.Start();
    }
```

Any idea?